# Advance url sef for joomla custom component

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, components

Hi there I googled for house but no solution...

I developed a component on joomla3

with The joomla sef the addreess of component is this:

```
orginal address: domain.com/index.php?option=com_bahaedini&keyword=22&year=2005&month=1&day=4
```

with menu: `domain.com/menu_name/view_name/keyword/2005/1/4`

without menu: `domain.com/component/bahaedini/view_name/keyword/2005/1/4`

My favariate domain is:`domain.com/keyword/2005/1/4`

But at least how can remove "view_name" or "component/bahaedini" in the URL?

I can remove it by hatccess but I can not sent parametrs to component...

I want to have at least on of these format:

```
domain.com/keyword/2005/1/4
domain.com/menu_name/keyword/2005/1/4
```

or

```
domain.com/view_name/keyword/2005/1/4
domain.com/bahaedini/keyword/2005/1/4



<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die ;


//http://127.0.0.1/archives?option=com_bahaedini&view=items&date=2014-12-9
function BahaediniBuildRoute(&$query)
{
       $segments = array();
       if(isset($query['view']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['view'];
                unset( $query['view'] );
       }

       if(isset($query['keyword']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['keyword'];
                unset( $query['keyword'] );
       }

       if(isset($query['year']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['year'];
                unset( $query['year'] );
       }
       if(isset($query['month']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['month'];
                unset( $query['month'] );
       }
       if(isset($query['day']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['day'];
                unset( $query['day'] );
       }


       return $segments;
}

//http://127.0.0.1/archives?option=com_bahaedini&view=items&date=2014-12-9
function BahaediniParseRoute($segments)
{
       $vars = array();


       switch($segments[0])
       {

               case 'items':
                       $vars['view'] = 'items';

                       if(isset($segments[2]))
                       {
                       $year = explode( ':', $segments[2] );
                       $vars['year'] =  (int)$year[0];
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[3]))
                       {
                       $month = explode( ':', $segments[3] );
                       $vars['month'] = (int)$month[0]; 
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[4]))
                       {
                       $day = explode( ':', $segments[4] );
                       $vars['day'] = (int)$day[0]; 
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[1]))
                       {
                       $search = explode( ':', $segments[1] );
                       $vars['keyword'] = (int)$search[0]; 
                       }

                       break; 


       }
       return $vars;
}?>
```

Comment: You have to have component because you have no way of controlling whether either keyword or bahaedini is used as a menu alias or alias in some other component, hence component is a reserved word that prevents the possibility of two pages having the same url by making component/bahaedini. What you should do as your found is make a menu item and also write a custom router for your component so ou don't have the view name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can give me more info?...I edited my qestion with router.php code...how can change it to hide view name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything set to `$segments` will appear in the url. So this `$segments[] = $query['view'];` adds the view to the url. Since your parser automatically sets the view, still unset the view in the build function, but don't push it into `$segments`:

```
function BahaediniBuildRoute(&$query)
{
   $segments = array();
   if(isset($query['view']))
   {
            unset( $query['view'] );
   }
   ...
```

Naturally, you may have to adjust your parser, since now the number of segments will be different, so you will need different index values.

Comment: Great...thanks....I underestand $segments rule and with a bit change in ParseRoute function I could solve my problem...:)